# Rails: problem with application.html.erb layout file and application_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a strange error that came about when I changed my app from mongrel to mod_rails.

My app changes from a two column layout to a three column layout depending on where the user is in the app. My application layout relies on several helpers to put the divs in the right place.

In application_helper.rb:

```
  def left_column_layouts
   if  params[:controller] == "users" && params[:action] == "show" ||
       params[:controller] == "friendships" && params[:action] == "index" ||
       params[:controller] == "tags" && params[:action] == "index"
       true
   else
       false
   end 
end
```

I also have similar logic for where the three column layouts.

Then, in my layout file:

```
    <% if left_column_layouts %>
    <div class="colmask leftmenu">
    <div class="colleft">
  <%= yield %>
    </div>
    </div>
<% elsif three_columns_with_blank_sides %>
<div class="colmask threecol">
<div class="colmid">
<div class="colleft">
    <%= yield %>
<div class="col2">
</div>
<div class="col3">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% else #Three column layout %>
    <div class="colmask threecol">
    <div class="colmid">
    <div class="colleft">
<%= yield %>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This worked well until I changed to mod rails. I can't imagine why mod rails would make this part of the app simply not work.

Interesting note: I went to the https parts of my site and the layout was loading without a problem. My server support guys said I should clear the cache but the problem persists.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't be a problem with mod_rails. What else did you do?

Comment: Let's see...

I did modify the layout file a bit to put in a new header picture, but I can't imagine this has anything to do with the helper not loading. The fact that it's loading on the secure pages and not the regular ones really puzzles me.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what do you mean?  Nothing rendered? Error generated?  View the source of the rendered page and post it here.

Comment: A certain part of the application layout file doesn't appear in the source of the rendered page as it should. The header and footer appear just fine but the column divs (which depend on the helper) do not load...

Comment: which version of ruby do you use with mod rails? REE?

Comment: Oh, and it's working just fine on the local server...

Comment: and another reason can be in helper file access permissions

Comment: @fl00r
I'm not sure about the ruby version. Sorry for my n00bishness. Could that be the problem and is there a way to check it?

Comment: try to give chmod 777 to all files in your projects for test on server

Comment: @fl00r I don't think it's the helper file access permissions, because the helpers seem to be working otherwise.

Comment: check out `ruby -v` on server and on your localhost, the check Apache (nginx) config files if there is another ruby version writed

Comment: it can be partial file permission trouble

Comment: I got 1.8.6 on localhost and the server. I don't know where the Apache config file is... I think I can't edit it because I'm on a shared server maybe?

I'm not sure how chmod works, and I'm a little hesitant to mess with permissions because of it. Know any good overviews on it and how it pertains to rails?

Comment: I fixed the problem with a bit of a hack. I placed the missing divs directly into the view files instead of relying on the application layout to put them in. The permissions for the view files are all 644.

Comment: "My server support guys said I should clear the cache"... what did you do to achieve this?

Comment: @yar
I just cleared the cache through my browser. Since I was able to make some quick (admittedly hackish) fixes the cache didn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: @Kenji Crosland, they most likely referred to clearing the cache on the server-side. You may want to ask them what steps to take to clear the cache. The fact that it works with SSL is disturbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old post, but just to make sure that others would see it. If I correctly understand what you want, I believe the problem lies in the logic used in your condition.

If you want to display left column when controller:action is users:show or friendships:index or tags:index, your logic condition is incorrect. You need parentheses to correct them.

For example, let's say users is 'A', show is 'B', friendships is 'C', index of friendships is 'D', tags is 'E', and index of tags is 'F'.

Your code represents A && B || C && D || E && F, but I believe what you want is (A && B) || (C && D) || (E && F). Because A && B || C && D || E && F is not equal to (A && B) || (C && D) || (E && F), the method may return incorrect result. To be more clear, let say all params from A to E are true but F is false. Your method will return false which is supposed to be true. That may be the case.

Comment: Hey Taywin. Thanks for the help! The server did a major upgrade and now the problem is gone. Wierd. I should implement these changes though to make sure it doesn't happen again.